# How do I make one div move with the other?

Tags: css, html

I'm relatively new to editting html and css etc, and I feel this is easy to be resolved, but I cannot figure it out..
I'm editting a theme on tumblr, the links are below the description, but if the description is too long it gets covered by the links.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvLtf.png]

I know there is a way to make the links move lower when the description gets too long, but I don't know how to do that. I think it may have to do with a span or div class?

Here is my coding:  (desc is for the description)

http://freetexthost.com/oy6wxvnut3

Do I need to use a div class or span class instead/change the "#link1" etc. to ".link1" ? Do I need to use a wrapper? Should I move the titlebar div from in between the description and links?

I do want the description and links to stay where they are on the screen when scrolling.

I hope this makes sense!

Comment: It is best to create a JSFiddle with your code.

Comment: My goodness, man.  Knock off a 0 or two on that margin (at least for the example)

Comment: All I want is to know how to make the links move along with the description as it gets longer, to avoid overlapping?

Comment: You are using fixed positions. Use relative instead.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DMZBF/)

Ok, So here is what i found.  You are over using the `position:fixed` attribute.  You have all your links and the description box as fixed, which allows you to place the elements anywhere you want and lets the content stay fixed while scrolling, but the flip side is that it takes the element out of flow.  This means your elements have no context and can't be made content relative.  What you need to do is rework the design such that only a parent container is `position:fixed` and all the children of that parent retain their "in flow" attributes.  In the following scenario, only the parent should be position fixed:

```
 _________________________
|__________window_________|
|                         |
|         _____________   |
|        |____parent___|  |
|        | description |  |
|        | child child |  |
|        | child child |  |
|        | child child |  |
|         -------------   |
 -------------------------
```

What you have is description and all the child elements as fixed.  Get them back into flow with each other and then get the parent container positioned if necessary.